# To separate comments and data in .txt file by C++ fstream

Tags: c++, fstream

I have some .txt files with the following pattern:

```
#Some comments here

bull rocket 3
trailer laker -12

#More comments there

Warriors Pacers 9
```

Basically, there are some comments around starting with a # 
and other lines contain two strings followed by an int

I need those two strings and one int one by one to process
and I have to ignore any blank line or line starting with #

I am thinking to use ifstream.get() to read the first char and
discard the whole line if it is a #

But I am stuck when it comes to the data. How can I read a char
and then get the first string? i.e., I find a 'b' and then I need
the "bull". What should I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <fstream>
 #include <sstream>
 #include <string>
 using namespace std;
 int main()
 {
        fstream f1("f1.data");
        string line,w1,w2;
        int num;

        while ( getline(f1,line) ) {
                if ( istringstream(line) >> w1 >> w2 >> num
                  && w1[0] != '#' )
                        cout << w1 <<' '<< w2 <<' '<< num << '\n';
        }
 }
```

This is lightweight text scanning, not the lexer for a javascript interpreter or some such; clarity wins over everything, so use the parts of C++ that get it into scripting-language to to full advantage.

Comment: np, I stripped an unneeded temp.

Answer (score 3):

Use "`while (std::getline(is, line)) {`" to read the file stream (`std::istream is`) a line (`std::string line`) at a time.

If `line` is `empty()` or starts with `#`, `continue`. You may wish to trim any leading whitespace before performing this check.

Otherwise, parse the line (probably using `std::istringstream iss(line); iss >> first >> second >> value;`). There are lots of great examples elsewhere on StackOverflow on how to do this bit.

Answer (score 2):

Something in the lines of:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
int main(){
  std::ifstream input("input");
  while (input.good()) {
    char c = input.peek();
    if (c == '#' || c == '\n') {
      input.ignore(256, '\n');
      continue;
    }   
    std::string s1, s2; 
    int i;
    input >> s1 >> s2 >> i;
    if (input.good())
      std::cout << s1 << " - " << s2 << " - " << i << std::endl;
  }
  input.close();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sample code:

```
    ifstream in("file.txt");
    if (!in.is_open())
        return false;

    string line;
    while (getline(in, line))
    {
        istringstream iss(line, istringstream::in);

        if (!line.length())
            continue;

        if (line[0] == '#') // Ignore the line starts with #
            continue;

       vector<string> words;

        string word;
        while (iss >> word)
        {
                words.push_back(word);
        }

        // now you have all words of current line
        // you can use them to parse your file
    }
```

This is a sample code, you should skip white-spaces before #. For example left trimming is useful.

Comment: What is vector?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to @MM.'s answer, you could use the new `<regex>` capabilities of C++ 11. Note, however, that currently not all standard libraries implement this fully, so you might want to also fall back to [`Boost.regex`](http://www.boost.org/libs/regex) if necessary.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

// note: Most C++11 regex implementations are not up to scratch, offer
// Boost.regex as an alternative.
#ifdef USE_BOOST_REGEX
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
namespace std
{
  using ::boost::regex;
  using ::boost::regex_match;
  using ::boost::smatch;
}
#else
#include <regex>
#endif

#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  // open input file
  std::ifstream in("file.txt");
  if (!in.is_open()) return 1;
  // ECMAScript syntax!
  std::regex empty_or_comment_re("\\s*(?:#.*)?");
  // note: only matches integers
  std::regex values_re("\\s*(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(-?\\d+)\\s*");
  // will contain the results
  std::vector<std::tuple<std::string, std::string, int> > results;
  size_t lineno = 0; // for error reporting
  std::string line;
  // read lines
  while (getline(in, line))
  {
    ++lineno;
    // match empty or comment lines
    if (regex_match(line, empty_or_comment_re)) continue;
    // match lines containing data
    std::smatch match;
    if (!regex_match(line, match, values_re))
    {
      std::cerr<< "ERROR: malformed line in file.txt, line " << lineno
        << ".\n";
      return 1;
    }
    // read integer from match
    int n;
    std::istringstream iss(match[3]);
    iss >> n;
    // append to results
    results.push_back(std::make_tuple(match[1], match[2], n));
  }
}
```